# How do I move all 3 windows 10 partitions into 1 extended partition

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask but hopefully it is. My Windows 10 installation is using up 3 partitions on my hard drive which has a limit of 4 partitions. The 4th(and last) partition is an extended partition with Ubuntu 20.04 installed on it. Currently I'm trying to switch to Arch Linux but there's no way for me to make the partition since I've used up all 4. I want to keep my Windows and Ubuntu partitions.

My question is how can I take all 3 Windows 10 partitions and pack them into one extended partition? If I can move all 3 of those partitions into an extended partition it would free up 2 partitions.

Heres a screenshot of [Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlUWE.png)

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how can I take all 3 Windows 10 partitions and pack
> them into one extended partition?

You cannot do this. One of the three is the UEFI partition and is needed to start the computer. It cannot be combined with the data partition.

Your data partition is what it says and is needed.

The other of the three is the recovery partition. It also cannot be combined with the data partition. You will inevitably need this one day so do not delete it.

If your hard drive has the limit you say, make Ubuntu a virtual machine. That will solve your issue. I have not seen such a limit on a modern computer.

Comment: If it is a "UEFI partition" then the disk would be partitioned as GPT and the 4 partition limit would not apply.

Comment: @Mokubai Correct but this isn't an UEFI installation, it's Legacy and very likely for no reason at all. It happens that the Ubuntu installer now creates an ESP even in Legacy/BIOS installations for... Reasons (maybe to account for a future conversion?).

Comment: Set your machine to GPT and you can use more partitions.  If you wish to remain Legacy then as I noted, use a virtual machine for Ubuntu.

Comment: John, as far as I know there is no easy conversion to GPT as the Windows boot process has to be changed as well.

Comment: There is no simple way but GPT should be used to allow more partitions, and to set up Windows 10 properly. Legacy is old and should not be used.